# There seems a logical error in TSQL Computation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

In the code below, my goal is to read certain information about person in another table, then perform calculation then insert the result in another table. This  need to scanning entire table perform the same computation before inserting the values to the second table. When i run the code, on point 22 get inserted in the scores table even thought there are various ranks.below is my code:

```
    DECLARE @PID NCHAR(4), @rank nvarchar(20),@JoinDate datetime,@Amt int,
    @LengthOfService int,@RowNum int
    select  @PID=Max(No_) from dbo.Person
    select @RowNum=COUNT(*)FROM dbo.Person
    select @JoinDate=[Employment Date] from dbo.Person where No=@PID
    select @rank=Grade from dbo.Personwhere where No=@PID
    While @RowNum>0
     BEGIN
      IF(@rank='Point01' OR @rank='Point02' )
     BEGIN
     SET @Amt=10
    END
    ELSE if(@rank='Point03')
    BEGIN
    set @Amt=5
    END
     ELSE IF(@rank='Point04' OR @rank='Point05')
    BEGIN
    set @Amt=22
    END

     INSERT INTO   dbo.Scores(EmpID,total)
      VALUES(@PID,@Amt)
      set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1  

     END
```

Comment: Why don't you just write an `INSERT SELECT` statement? Why the loop and why the `triggers` tag? You don't either

Comment: This is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . You have a problem X, calculating some sort of rank. You think you need loops to do it (you don't) and when you get into trouble you ask about the loops, not the *actual* problem. What are you trying to calculate? Post example source and result data

Comment: BTW SQL Server has a lot of ranking functions like ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, NTILE etc. You can use the `OVER` clause to calculate running aggregates. You can *JOIN* two tables to get matching rows. You can use a `CASE` clause inside a `SUM` to convert textual data to numbers, although it would be easier to join with a lookup table. Whatever you want to do, doesn't require loops and all those variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can get expected output by using only one select statement no need of while loop and extra parameters. Check this -

```
     INSERT INTO   dbo.Scores(EmpID,total)
        select max(p.no)  over (partition by p.no order by p.no desc) as EmpId,  
               case WHEN grade='Point01' OR  grade='Point02' THEN 10
                    WHEN grade='Point03' THEN 5 
                    WHEN grade='Point04' OR grade='Point05' THEN 22 END as Amt   
        FROM person p, personwhere pw
        WHERE p.no =pw.no
```